# Radio button checked property issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

My Html code is as below.But always checked final option button as selected one.How can I fixed this?

```
<div id="employee" style="margin: 7px 0;">
            <div>
                   <input id="james-johnson" type="radio" name="employee" value="james-johnson" checked="checked"><label for="james-johnson">James Johnson</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="boss-hog" type="radio" name="employee" value="boss-hog" checked="unchecked"><label for="boss-hog">Boss Hog</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="jake-sanders" type="radio" name="employee" value="jake-sanders" checked="unchecked"><label for="jake-sanders">Jake Sanders</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="dawn" type="radio" name="employee" value="dawn" checked="unchecked"><label for="dawn">Dawn</label>
               </div>

        </div>
```

ASPX Code is as below

```
<div id="employee" style="margin: 7px 0;">
            <% foreach (var employee in Model.Provider.Employees)
               {  %><div>
                   <input id="<%: employee.Key %>"
                       type="radio" name="employee" value="<%: employee.Key %>" checked="<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ?? "unchecked" %>" /><label for="<%: employee.Key  %>"><%: employee.Name%></label>
               </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE (When I applied @Satpal method):**

```
<div id="employee" style="margin: 7px 0;">
            <div>
                   <input id="james-johnson" type="radio" name="employee" value="james-johnson" checked="checked"><label for="james-johnson">James Johnson</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="boss-hog" type="radio" name="employee" value="boss-hog" checked=""><label for="boss-hog">Boss Hog</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="jake-sanders" type="radio" name="employee" value="jake-sanders" checked=""><label for="jake-sanders">Jake Sanders</label>
               </div>
            <div>
                   <input id="dawn" type="radio" name="employee" value="dawn" checked=""><label for="dawn">Dawn</label>
               </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What exactly you applied? `When I applied @Satpal method`, I am expacting either only `checked` for `james-johnson`

Comment: @Satpal like this :checked="<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ? "checked" : "" %>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As The checked attribute is a boolean attribute.
When present, it specifies that an  element should be pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.

Set `checked` attribute only if `employee is Selected` otherwise don't set it

```
<input id="<%: employee.Key %>"
   type="radio" name="employee" value="<%: employee.Key %>" 
   "<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ? "checked" : "" %>" />
   <label for="<%: employee.Key  %>"><%: employee.Name%>
   </label>
```

Modified Code

```
"<%: employee.IsEmployeeSelected ? "checked" : "" %>"
```

Convert `employee.IsEmployeeSelected` to boolean property

EDIT: As per comment **Currentely it's "checked" and null**

```
"<%: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.IsEmployeeSelected) ? employee.IsEmployeeSelected : "" %>"
```

Or simply set `<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ?? "" %>` like

```
<input <%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ?? "" %> />
```

### UPDATE

As OP has updated the field `IsEmployeeSelected` to boolean

```
 public bool IsEmployeeSelected { get; set; }
```

Thus use `<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ? "checked" : "" %>` instead of `checked="<%:employee.IsEmployeeSelected ? "checked" : "" %>"`

Comment: It says "cannot implicitly convert type string to bool"

Comment: Is That means employee.IsEmployeeSelected should be boolean one ?

Comment: What about nullable boolean ?

Comment: Currentely it's "checked" and null.

Comment: Plz check my UPDATE section.Stil the out put is same.Final one selected.I have changed my property into boolean as  public bool IsEmployeeSelected { get; set; }.No luck ?